# Android paypal integration

Tags: android, paypal

I have integrated paypal within my Android application.
I have a main activity - and about activity, in which I show the paypal button. About activity accessed from the main Activity.
Paypal object is initialized in a thread, created from the OnCreate of the Application object.

I am now facing 2 issues:
1. Paypal button works only the first time I click on it. The second time does not work. I have to go back to the main menu and then back to the about Activity, then it works again.
Here is:

Code to add the paypal button to the layout:

```
mDonateButton = AppObj.Instance().GetPayPalObj().getCheckoutButton( mCaller, 
                                                                            PayPal.BUTTON_152x33, 
                                                                            CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY );
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
mDonateButton.setLayoutParams(params);
mDonateButton.setGravity( Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL );
mDonateButton.setOnClickListener( this );

LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById( R.id.donateLayout );
container.addView(mDonateButton);
```

The OnClick related code:

```
                PayPalPayment newPayment = new PayPalPayment();
                newPayment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal(Integer.parseInt(info)));
                newPayment.setCurrencyType("USD");
                newPayment.setRecipient("xxx@xxx.com");
                newPayment.setPaymentType(PayPal.PAYMENT_TYPE_NONE);
                newPayment.setMerchantName("xxx");
                Intent paypalIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(newPayment, mCaller);
                (mCaller).startActivityForResult(paypalIntent, 1);
```

1. Second issue I have.... Since I init the paypal obj in the BG, if I access the About activity (in which the paypal button created) BEFORE the paypal finished initializing, the I crash......
   Any ideas about it?

Thanks
Yoav

Comment: have u find the solution?

Answer (score 3):

In case you are still looking for an answer, I have one

If you have a look at `getCheckoutButton` method, it takes `Context` as parameter, so when the `Activity` is for e.g. say Paused which happens when you start another `Activity`, the instance of the `CheckoutButton` is lost somehow.

I fixed is by using `updateButton` method in onResume of the Activity

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        /**
         * The CheckoutButton has to be updated each time the Activity is
         * resumed, otherwise the onClickListener of CheckoutButton will not work
         **/
        if (mCheckOutBtn != null && (mCheckOutBtn instanceof CheckoutButton))
            mCheckOutBtn.updateButton();
        super.onResume();
    }
```

This works considering you initialized `PayPal` library and `CheckoutButton` in `onCreate` of `Activity`.